# Cannot find the master page used by my default page

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-designer

I have my SharePoint website (I did not create it so I am trying to get used to everything I find inside it).

### Identifying the master page

In my home screen in SharePoint Designer 2013 I can find my default page and the possibility to edit it. After entering the edit  mode for my default page I can clearly see the link to the master page:

```
<%@ Page language="C#" 
MasterPageFile="~masterurl/default.master" 
Inherits="Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.WebControls.PersonalWebPartPage,
    Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal,Version=16.0.0.0,
    Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" 
meta:webpartpageexpansion="full" meta:progid="SharePoint.WebPartPage.Document" %>
```

To get to the master page I look here: `MasterPageFile="~masterurl/default.master"` of course.

### Locating the master page

I try to go to the `Master Pages` section of my Navigation Pane in SharePoint Designer 2013 but I cannot see the master page pointed by my default page.

[image]

What am I missing?

Comment: Generally speaking, I don't apply SP masterpages in the layout the way you would with winforms. I'd remove the MasterPageFile attribute and define in the site settings.

Answer (score 5):

I don't know this helps or not. I have some experience over Sharepoint 2007.

Here, the default master page is located at Master Page Gallery. You can find it by browsing `/_catalogs/masterpage/Forms/Default.aspx`

**UPDATE**

I googled a little about Sharepoint 2013. The v4.master I can see in the screenshot is the Default masterpage for Sites created from Sharepoint 2013 Designer. Actually what happens, the `~masterurl/default.master` is a dynamic token which refers to a property `SPWeb.MasterUrl`. Here the physical name of the master page is stored. At runtime, the value in this property replaces the `~masterurl/default.master` token in content pages. By default, the property value is set to `v4.master`.

Comment: Where can I see the place where these properties/aliases are stored? Thankyou

Comment: This is a `Public String` property that has been declared in `Microsoft.SharePoint.dll` assembly.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the master page that is used on the current site under site settings > Master page. Depending on if its the Site Master Page or the System Master page it could change the location. You can also go to Site Settings and click on Master pages and page under the Web Designer Galleries to go the list that will contain your master page.

If you are trying to edit just the one page then you should be able to find the page under Site Pages. 
The master page used should be found under Master pages unless you don't have sufficient access then a custom master page might not be visible.